# Why do i have so ugly creases on my render

Tags: rendering

don't know why but i have very ugly creases when i plug my normal map in.
I fixed my normal map and tryed to delete all creases but still have no result , model is very ugly , this is my 3rd character and for very first time i have so ugly results ;/
https://dropmefiles.com/M9ON9
with out normal map everything looks very good.

Comment: hello, could you please use another download platform? Also, don't forget to pack the image inside the file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.

Comment: Set the Color Space to Non-Color on the normal map's node in the shader editor.

Comment: Your mesh looks like a low poly mesh with shade smooth enabled. Add a Subdivision Surface modifier?

Comment: ty guys for attantion, have not expected so fast answers , cant upload on blender exchange dunno why .https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1iV-v_eb7VlqOP0orvktBDGxM5DeI-nFU mb this link is ok ? non color data is enabled .

Comment: or this https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iV-v_eb7VlqOP0orvktBDGxM5DeI-nFU?usp=sharing